# Best way to show app version starting jetty project

Tags: java, maven, jetty, versioning

The project based on the `jetty` at startup must display the application version in console. Is desired to show version data just after jetty says he started. However, the app architecture does not allow to do so directly from my code. 
Perhaps this can be done using configuration files?

**Editing1:**
Project starts as `jetty server` from compiled with maven `war` file and on momet of start I have no access to `pom.xml`. Also, after start no java methods are calling. `Jetty server` waits while somebody connect to it via browser or rest api (not sure how it works). Only after a user request my code will be called.

So, I need to show version of my project just after `jetty server` run with my compiled `war` file. How can I do it?

Comment: You can read your `pom.xml` from your `Java` code to get the version.

Comment: I need to show version to users, which starts my project from dep package on servers. I can't to ask them look into pom.xml file)

Comment: No need to ask them to see your `pom.xml`. you have to implement a way to read your `pom.xml`

Comment: So, this is my question. How to show my project version after jetty completely run?

Comment: Just after start `Jetty` use 
            `reader = new FileReader("pom.xml");
            MavenXpp3Reader xpp3Reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
            Model model = xpp3Reader.read(reader);
            return model.getProperties().get("VERSION").toString();`

Comment: Thank you, Ruchira Gayan Ranaweera, for replies, but it not what I asked for. I will notice that I can work with MavenXpp3Reader when I will be need to work with `pom.xml` from my java code.